# Java could not delete file because it is opened in Java SE BINARY

Tags: java, file

I have taken a look at multiple topics where people had the same problem but I cant find a clear solution on how to fix this.

I have a users.txt file, where I would like to check if a certain user is in the list. if the user is in the list I would like to delete him from the list.

This is done by copying over all the content of the users.txt files to a temp file except for the line which contains the given user. And then delete the users.txt file and rename the temp file to users.txt.

i keep getting the error that the file cannot be deleted because it is opened in Java SE BINARY. Any suggestions on how to fix this would be greatly appreciated!

Where I call the method:

```
     BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("C:/Users/Leroy/Documents/users.txt"));
        String registerUser;
        while ((registerUser = br.readLine()) != null) {
           if (registerUser.contains(removeuser)){
              removeLineFromFile("C:/Users/Leroy/Documents/users.txt", registerUser);
                            }
                        }
```

The method:

```
public void removeLineFromFile(String file, String lineToRemove) {
    try {
        File inFile = new File(file);

        if (!inFile.isFile()) {
            System.out.println("Parameter is not an existing file");
            return;
        }
        //Construct the new file that will later be renamed to the original filename.
        File tempFile = new File(inFile.getAbsolutePath()+ ".tmp");

        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file));
        PrintWriter pw = new PrintWriter(new FileWriter(tempFile));

        String line = null;

        //Read from the original file and write to the new
        //unless content matches data to be removed.
        while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
            if (!line.trim().equals(lineToRemove)) {
                pw.println(line);
                pw.flush();
            }
        }
        pw.close();
        br.close();

        //Delete the original file
        if (!inFile.delete()) {
            System.out.println("Could not delete file");
            return;
        }       
        //Rename the new file to the filename the original file had.
        if (!tempFile.renameTo(inFile))
            System.out.println("Could not rename file");
    }
```

Comment: You have two buffered readers open on the file you want to delete, did you try closing said readers before deleting the file?

Comment: Move file deleting logic outside of removeLineFromFile() method.First close bufferedreader and then try deleting it.

Comment: **If** you have all contents in an arraylist of somesorts, why not just overwrite the first file without creating a temp file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Prior to calling `removeLineFromFile` on the `"users.txt"` file, you opened another reader for it.  That reader is still open, and *that* is why your delete is failing.

Actually, there are other flaws in your code:

- The `while` loop in the calling context is repeatedly rewriting a file at the same time that it is reading it.  Considering that you are using a buffered reader to do the reading, there are opportunities for the loop to see partial lines due to the activity of the rewriter.
- Within the `removeLineFromFile` method, your code for opening and closing files is potentially leaky.  Resource handles (e.g. readers, writers, etc) should be closed in a `finally` block, or managed using "try with resources".
- Flushing after each line written is wasteful.

I'd rewrite the whole lot like this:

```
 File tempFile = new File(file.getAbsolutePath()+ ".tmp");
 try (BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(inFile));
      PrintWriter pw = new PrintWriter(new FileWriter(tempFile))) {
     String registerUser;
     while ((registerUser = br.readLine()) != null) {
        if (!registerUser.contains(removeuser)) {
            pw.println(line);
        }
     }
 }
 if (!inFile.delete()) {
     System.out.println("Could not delete file");
 } else if (!tempFile.renameTo(inFile))
     System.out.println("Could not rename file");
 }
```

(If you wanted to avoid "touching" the input file if there was no matching line, then you could set a flag if you found and removed a line ... etcetera.)